# Adding a description to android SwitchCompat widget

Tags: android, android-widget, switchcompat

I want to set a description to my SwitchCompat widget.
Anyone know how?

"android:text" is the leading text but I want to set a description or "summary". (I'm not very good with English)

**My Code:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/my_switch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/switch_title"
                android:button="@null"
                android:padding="20dp"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have to add a TextView in the same layout as the SwitchCompat like so https://github.com/Grarak/KernelAdiutor/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/switchcompat_cardview.xml